# Android Navigation Architecture: How to access Nested native component for Deep link

Tags: android-architecture-components, back-stack, android-navigation

I'm implementing Android navigation component and has using a nested graph. Component **D** is the guy who will handle this. But when I'm performing it throwing exception:

**`Fragment is unknown to this NavController`**

At one level it is pretty much clear that, Fragment-D redirected from Fragment-C, but what is possible solution in this case to get direct control on Fragment-D.

I checked same for Fragment-C and it is able to accessible but on back it throwing same error as stated.

Any suggestion!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment is unknown to this NavController` is not directly related to deep linking. It is a common error message when you want navigate to a destination which ist not part of the current navigation graph.
So in your case it seems like your app has at least 2 navigation graphs (i.e. 2 NavHostFragments) and you want to navigate from NavHostFragment A to a destination in NavHostFragment B.

Of course, the current NavController A does not know about fragment B. That is what the error message is telling you.